# Troublesome first use of Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, login

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 two days ago. Everything was OK until today, when the login only got as far as my desktop wallpaper, without showing launcher icons or the top bar. I couldn't do anything! After much swearing and angst I used the Recovery mode to get in. That allows me control but everything now is very slow and unresponsive. The system said I should expect that and all should be OK after the normal boot. But it is not! I thought there might be problems with contention between Fingerprint GUI (which I use) and the password entry. But neither fingerprint nor password login fixes the problem.
Can anyone suggest how I should proceed? Do I need a complete reinstall?

Comment: This is caused by a problem with the desktop settings which needs to be fixed via the console. Please see this duplicate question which has detailed instructions how to obtain a terminal and fix the problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: Many thanks! I followed the instrutions contained in the link, with some trepidation. I didn't really know how to respond to some of the questions but I must have done something right because the change has fixed the problem,. Thanks again for your response.